# why is not fast even if used multi threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, download

I used code as below for multi threads to download images, but I found that not so fast, I am not sure why, does anyone expalin for me?

Normal download:

```
for imageSecond in imageSeconds:
    urlServer = imageSecond.get("src")
    pathLocal = formatPath(downloadLocationPath, ntpath.basename(urlServer))
    downloadImage(browser, urlServer, pathLocal)    

def downloadImage(browser, urlServer, pathLocal):
```

Threads download:

```
ts = []
for imageSecond in imageSeconds:
    urlServer = imageSecond.get("src")
    pathLocal = formatPath(downloadLocationPath, ntpath.basename(urlServer))
    ts.append(createNewDownloadThread(browser, urlServer, pathLocal))

for t in ts:
    t.join()

def createNewDownloadThread(browser, urlServer, pathLocal):
    download_thread = threading.Thread(target=downloadImage, args=(browser, urlServer, pathLocal))
    download_thread.start()
    return download_thread#.join()

def downloadImage(browser, urlServer, pathLocal):
```

Comment: Most likely reason: the bottleneck is your network connection, putting more CPU kernels to use it simultaneosly does nothing to improve that.

Answer (score 0):

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join):

> **join(timeout=None)**
>   Wait until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates – either normally or through an unhandled exception – or until the optional timeout occurs.

So you're creating a thread, waiting that it completes the download and then create another thread for following download which is basically the same as your original solution.

**Update** You could use [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) which offers simple interface:

```
import concurrent.futures as cf

def square(x):
    return x*x

with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(square, i) for i in range(5)]
    cf.wait(futures)

    for f in futures:
        print(f.result())
```

Output:

```
0
1
4
9
16
```

With your code it would look something like this:

```
NUM_THREADS = 10
with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(NUM_THREADS) as executor:
    futures = []
    for imageSecond in imageSeconds:
        urlServer = imageSecond.get("src")
        pathLocal = formatPath(downloadLocationPath, ntpath.basename(urlServer))
        futures.append(executor.submit(downloadImage, browser, urlServer, pathLocal))

    cf.wait(futures)
```

Comment: If I don't use join what I found the download images are not what I need, what can I modify my code for parallel download but no errors?

Comment: @mikezang Added simple example with `concurrent.futures`. If you want to stick with `threading` create the threads first, store them to list and then `join` them one by one.

Comment: I just modified my code then speed is faster more than original 2 times, is there anyway to be more fast?

Answer (score -1):

Use code as below

```
ts = []

for:
    t = createThread()
    t.start()
    ts.append(t)

for t in ts:
    t.join()
```

to instead of code

```
for:
    t = createThread()
    t.start()
    t.join()
```